# How to plot on exactly rows of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

That's not easy to describe with words, so I will reveal a picture for you in order to understand:
[image]
As the image shows, I want to plot a line on each row separately based on their values on a data frame. Is it possible with Python libraries?

Comment: I thinks it's easier to print the numbers and texts using [`text`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html) over the lines than the other way round.

Comment: @Stef Yeah, that's easy, but not at the moment when I have 41 records. The plot will be confusing

Comment: maybe I couldn't make myself clear: my point was that it's easier to use matplotlib to print the contents of the dataframe onto the chart with the curves than to somehow try and draw lines onto the dataframe respresentation. The resulting plot would be the same.

Comment: @Stef Oh, now I got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example to get you started: it uses [`table`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.table.html) to plot the dataframe and overplots the stacked lines. The line for each row is shifted by `ymax`, the maximum value in the dataframe, to prevent overlapping.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# make sample data
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(41,5))
df.index = [f'Row {i}' for i in df.index]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,10))
ax.set_axis_off()

# plot data as table
plt.matplotlib.table.table(ax, df.applymap('{:.1f}'.format).values.tolist(), rowLabels=df.index, bbox=[0,0,1,1])

# plot curve over table
ymax = df.max().max()
ax.set_ylim(0, ymax * len(df))
ax.plot((df.to_numpy() + ((len(df) - 1 - df.reset_index(drop=True).index.to_numpy()) * ymax)[:, None]).T, color='C0')
```

[image]

---

To use alternating colors, you can set the [color cycler](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/color_cycle.html):

```
from cycler import cycler
# ...
ax.set_prop_cycle(cycler(color='rg'))
ax.plot((df.to_numpy() + ((len(df) - 1 - df.reset_index(drop=True).index.to_numpy()) * ymax)[:, None]).T)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to use two colours instead of one? I tried a list of colors but it gave me error

Comment: if you print all lines in one run as an array you need to use a color cycler, see updated answer

Comment: The problem was solved completely. Thanks!